# What is the purpose of this hole on Wacom Intuos Pro tablet?

Tags: graphics-tablet

My friend recently received a new digital drawing tablet (Wacom Intuos Pro). Among other features, there is a hole that resembles a charm hole found on mobile phones:

[image]

Other parts of the package (e.g. pen) do not have such holes, so it isn't possible to attach them using a band.
What is the purpose of this hole? Is it just for attaching various charms and such?

Comment: It's not some type of Kensington-type lock port is it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That looks to be the security lock slot. See #4 under the second picture at [Intuos Pro features](http://101.wacom.com/UserHelp/en/Features_IntuosPro.htm).

Answer (score 5):

It is a Kensington lock port. As described in the owners manual below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It is a hole to pass a security cable through in case you are using the tablet in a public place by many people, for example a school computer lab.