# What is this socket/port/connector on my laptop?

Tags: port, sockets, connector

[image: Unknown Socket]

I've have this socket on my laptop (Lenovo Z570).

What is this port and what is it used for?
And what does that symbol mean (I expected a LOCK symbol)?

Comment: It is for a lock. Kensington lock. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Security_Slot

Comment: thanks buddy! anyway you could have posted it as an answer instead of a comment!!

Comment: See also: http://superuser.com/questions/1020598/what-is-the-purpose-of-this-hole-on-wacom-intuos-pro-tablet

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That is a [Kensington lock](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kensington_Security_Slot) used for anti-theft purposes. It is attached by means of a cable from something stationary, such as a table, to the device. The cable will then lock at one end from the port, preventing theft. This is much like a bike and it being locked to a railing or something being anchored to prevent removal. An example of a Kensington lock and cable on a PowerBook G4 (from Wikipedia):

Without the lock installed:

[image]

With the lock installed:

[image]

Here, the lock is attached to the corresponding port on the G4, and to the table, preventing theft of the device. Another example of the lock being used:

[image]

There are many kinds of these locks, by the Kensington company. See [their page](https://www.kensington.com/us/us/4480/security) for details.

Comment: And in 99 of a 100 cases you can yank the lock straight out of the slot with only minimal damage to the laptop casing. Very expensive locks and only a deterrent to casual theft. A professional thief will simply use a bolt-cutter to remove the lock. Takes at most 30 seconds without damaging the laptop.

Comment: In 100 of 100 cases, this wire can be cut in two snips with a pair of pliers :/

Comment: Yup. Extremely easy to break/snap/yank and super annoying to the user all the time. This thing has no justification, regardless of its price

Comment: @Dr.Ping - Its value is that it deters entirely casual theft. From the kind of thief who doesn't habitually carry pliers.